# Select year overview like columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar

How can I create a select query to select every month and year column per column, so the result should be like this:
http://www.google.de/url?source=imglanding&ct=img&q=http://www.calenweb.com/png/en/2015/2015-yearly-calendar.png&sa=X&ei=Ma1IVeHLLtHjavfsgfAI&ved=0CAkQ8wc&usg=AFQjCNHw0gwp3G9-bSGGNspsZJjMqZbjBA

Of course, the format, colors... doesn't matter.

Any ideas? Is the problem clear?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? How do your tables look like?

Comment: Are you trying to Make a calendar?  You could have several `SELECT` statement (one for each month) utilizing `DATEPART` and `UNION` them together...

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL Server 2012. Yes, a calender is the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PIVOT to arrange the data and a tally table to calculate it:

```
DECLARE @year CHAR(4) = 2015

;WITH N1 (N) AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS 
(SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N)-1 FROM N1 AS N1 
 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2 CROSS JOIN N1 N3),
CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    month(dateadd(d, n, @year)) mon, 
    day(dateadd(d, n, @year)) monthday,
    convert(char(2), dateadd(d, n, @year), 5)+ ' ' 
      + left(datename(weekday, dateadd(d, n, @year)), 1) day
  FROM n2
  WHERE 
    @year < dateadd(year, 1, @year) - n
)
SELECT 
  [1] JAN, [2] FEB, [3] MAR, [4] APR, [5] MAY, [6] JUN, 
  [7] JUL, [8] AUG, [9] NOV, [10] OCT, [11] NOV, [12] [DEC]
FROM CTE
PIVOT
(min([day])  
FOR mon in([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])  
)AS p 
ORDER BY 1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/39)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
?>

<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
?>

<?php
$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>

<table width="200">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left">  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>M</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>W</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>F</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>n";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>n";
    else echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>n";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>n";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it;

```
select 
    A,
    B,
    C
from
    (select 1 as A) tblA
    inner join (select 2 as B) tblB on 1=1
    inner join (select 3 as C) tblC on 1=1
```

Imagine that every `(select 1 as X) tblX` would be a query to a table returning months with `where month=[1...12]` in each. No matter what the result youre getting, you get as many columns as you type more inner joins like that (or outer left joins...).

12 of those and you cover whole year...

Answer (score 1):

i found

```
    SELECT
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.01.2015'),'MM') = '01' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.01.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as Januar,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.02.2015'),'MM') = '02' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.02.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as Februar,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.03.2015'),'MM') = '03' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.03.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as März,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.04.2015'),'MM') = '04' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.04.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as April,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.05.2015'),'MM') = '05' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.05.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as Mai,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.06.2015'),'MM') = '06' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.06.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as Juni,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.07.2015'),'MM') = '07' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.07.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as Juli,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.08.2015'),'MM') = '08' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.08.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as August,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.09.2015'),'MM') = '09' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.09.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as September,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.10.2015'),'MM') = '10' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.10.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as Oktober,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.11.2015'),'MM') = '11' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.11.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as November,
CASE WHEN format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.12.2015'),'MM') = '12' then format(DATEADD(Day,Number,'01.12.2015'),'dd.MM.yyyy') else null end  as Dezember
FROM  master..spt_values 
WHERE Type='P'
AND DATEADD(day,Number,'01.01.2015') <= DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, '01.01.2015')), DATEADD(mm, 1, '01.01.2015'))
```

did it!